# Aws appsync: possible to do two putitems in one request with a dynamodb resolver?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

In aws appsync, i’d like to make one call (start_game(phrase:”foo”)), that will write to two seperate dynamodb tables (gams and turns).  I’m sure i can do this using a lambda resolver, but would love to avoid the extra complixity.

Is there a way to do two putitem (to two different tables), in a single dynamodb mutation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been added to AWS AppSync via the Batch Resolver feature. You can see a tutorial here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html

For this specific question, you can use the `BatchPutItem` to write multiple items to one or more tables. You do this through the `tables` key in the resolver. For one table it looks like this:

```
#set($postsdata = [])
#foreach($item in ${ctx.args.posts})
    $util.qr($postsdata.add($util.dynamodb.toMapValues($item)))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchPutItem",
    "tables" : {
        "Posts": $utils.toJson($postsdata)
    }
}
```

For two tables it looks similar:

```
## Convert tempReadings arguments to DynamoDB objects
#set($tempReadings = [])
#foreach($reading in ${ctx.args.tempReadings})
    $util.qr($tempReadings.add($util.dynamodb.toMapValues($reading)))
#end

## Convert locReadings arguments to DynamoDB objects
#set($locReadings = [])
#foreach($reading in ${ctx.args.locReadings})
    $util.qr($locReadings.add($util.dynamodb.toMapValues($reading)))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchPutItem",
    "tables" : {
        "locationReadings": $utils.toJson($locReadings),
        "temperatureReadings": $utils.toJson($tempReadings)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this apply only for insert? I am trying to update the existing records with batchPutItem as mentioned above and facing some error as mentioned bellow.

Can't resolve value (/batchUpdateDslVehicleStateMutation) : type mismatch error, expected type LIST.

Comment: @Desmond batch operations only work for Put, Delete, and Read. Not update.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Does that mean AppSync is does not support batch update operation. Then what is the solution for this. Should i create another lambda resolver which inturn will update the dynamodb.

Comment: @Desmond it's not AppSync that doesn't support update, DynamoDB does not support updates for batch operations. AppSync can only support what the data source supports.

Comment: yes you are correct. DynamoDB BatchWrite supports batch OUT (new items) and Delete. We need to use Update instead. I have used lambda Resolver for this purpose so that it will write for the array we pass and resturn a array of result back to appsync. Which can be sent to the subscribers back as array.

Comment: fyi, a/o Oct 2022 "conditions" are not supported with BatchPutItem: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-batch-put-item

Answer (score 3):

As of now, the only way to accomplish this is with a Lambda resolver.

With that being said, we have heard the request to support this use case from several customers, and will take this as a +1 to supporting it!

Comment: That would be great, thanks Jeff!   I also would love the ability to insert dates also.

Comment: @MichaelEconomy this is now available in AppSync, see my response below. Reading or Deleting from one or more tables is also possible. For dates, you could do this with $util.time helpers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#time-helpers-in-util-time